# How to get data from Photon eventContent dictionary

Tags: c++, dictionary, photon

We are receiving this callback using ExitGames Photon Realtime engine when an event is fired

```
customEventAction(int playerNr, 
                  nByte eventCode,
                  const ExitGames::Common::Object& eventContent)
```

If the object is a string we use this code to extract it

```
ExitGames::Common::JString str = 
    ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::JString>(eventContent).getDataCopy();
```

However, the object being sent is a dictionary. It's being sent from the server using BroadcastEvent.

How do we get data out of it ?

We've tried this, but it doesn't make any sense:

```
ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<byte,ExitGames::Common::Object>  pdic
    = ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<byte,ExitGames::Common::Object>>(eventContent).getDataCopy();
```

I've found code to get the data from a hashtable, but that doesn't work either.

thanks

Shaun

Comment: Are you sure that the dictonary is of the type `Dictionary<byte,ExitGames::Common::Object>`? What do you mean by *"it doesn't make any sense"*? What do you mean by *"hat doesn't work either"*? Please be more specific.

Comment: And is there a reason your `customEventAction` doesn't await `const Dictionary<byte,ExitGames::Common::Object>&` as third parameter?

Comment: ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<byte,ExitGames::Common::Object>  pdic = ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<byte,ExitGames::Common::Object>>(eventContent).getDataCopy();

Comment: How does that answer my questions?

Comment: The code above is what I'm using to cast the object to a dictionary type, but it doesn't actually give any meaningful results out.

Comment: I'm giving up - You obviously don't want to give more information.

Comment: The dictionary is sent from the server as the type Dictionary<byte, ExitGames::Common::Object> but the callback is called in the client code from the library with the signature above. From what I understand you have to cast the object to the correct type in your code. It works when we cast the object to a string, but I can't find how to cast it as a dictionary anywhere.

Comment: I foudn this code to cast the object to a hashtable, as I had also rad that a dictionary was a type of hashtable, but again, that didn't produce results that matched the data being sent.

ExitGames::Common::Hashtable htab = ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::Hashtable>(eventContent).getDataCopy();

Comment: I also tried changing the parameters of the customEventAction to what you suggested, but that callback was not called - the one with the third parameter of const ExitGames::Common::Object& eventContent was called

Answer (score 2):

```
ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<nByte, ExitGames::Common::Object> dic = ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<nByte, ExitGames::Common::Object> >(eventContent).getDataCopy();
```

is absolutely correct and works for me.

The cause of your problem must be inside another line.

When you replace the implementations of sendEvent() and customEventAction() in demo_loadBalancing inside one of the Photon C++ client SDKs with the following snippets, then that demo successfully sends and receives a Dictionary:

send:

```
void NetworkLogic::sendEvent(void)
{
    ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::JString> obj(L"test");
    ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<nByte, ExitGames::Common::Object> dic;
    dic.put(1, obj);
    mLoadBalancingClient.opRaiseEvent(false, dic, 0);
}
```

receive:

```
void NetworkLogic::customEventAction(int /*playerNr*/, nByte /*eventCode*/, const ExitGames::Common::Object& eventContent)
{
    EGLOG(ExitGames::Common::DebugLevel::ALL, L"");
    ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<nByte, ExitGames::Common::Object> dic = ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::Dictionary<nByte, ExitGames::Common::Object> >(eventContent).getDataCopy();
    const ExitGames::Common::Object* pObj = dic.getValue(1);
    ExitGames::Common::JString str = ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<ExitGames::Common::JString>(pObj).getDataCopy();
    mpOutputListener->write(L"received the following string as Dictionary value: " + str);
}
```

This gives me the following line of output on the receiving client:

> received the following string as Dictionary value: test